# Firebase Storage images are blocked for some users

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Some of our users are getting this error when opening images that are stored in Firebase Storage. They are opening the images with a browser not our app. However the majority of users can open them with no trouble at all. Why would a small percentage of users get Access denied to public images?

```
XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
    <Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>Access denied.</Message>
    <Details>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Details>
    <StringToSign>GET 1700048110 /ai-art-7c643.appspot.com/images/2Dc2YVftntdkCqSqQk0L4iI2/d7f4a0c86acca9a7bf6459404a97.jpg</StringToSign>
    </Error>
```

Here is a link to an example image.
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ai-art-7c643.appspot.com/o/FCMImages%2FImpressionist.jpg?alt=media

This image was uploaded through the Firebase console. So there is no code to show.
Also the same users could download the images a day ago with no issues. Neither Firebase or Google Cloud is currently reporting any outages.

Instructions to recreate:

1. From the Firebase console. In the "Storage" section. Click "Upload file". Upload a jpeg image.
2. Click on the image name in the list to open the side panel. Then click on the name under the image. That will open a new tab with a url to the image.
3. Copy that url
4. Send that url to a hundred or so people. Some will get the XML error when they open the image in a browser.

I've been getting emails with screen shots all day. I respond with a link to the sample image above and they can't open it. Based on the volume of complaints, it's probably about 1% of our users.

The images open for me when using incognito mode or wget.

Our security rules are simple:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
        // Everyone can read no one can write (Cloud Functions bypasses rules)
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }

    // Allow the requestor to read or delete or write any resource on a path under the
    // user directory.
    match /users/{userId}/{anyUserFile=**} {
      allow read, delete, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain how people triggering and observing this error, so that somone else could possibly duplicate the behavior.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the answer is that Firebase had a service outage.

https://status.firebase.google.com/

The outage just had not been updated when I checked.